# C# Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm

Tags: c#, security, encryption, asp.net-core, aes

I've seen a few other posts with this issue, but I'm not sure how to apply them to my scenario. The strange part is that I ran this successfully last night and when I came back to it today, it's throwing the `CryptographicException` 
`Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.`

The other posts reference the way the IV is handled but that seems to be wrapped in the `AesManaged` class.

What do I need to adjust here to resolve this?

```
public class SymetricEncryptionHelper
{
    private static int Rfc2898KeygenIterations = 100;
    private static int AesKeySizeInBits = 128;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an encrypted version of the plain text string and it's salt
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainTextString"></param>
    /// <param name="encryptionPassword"></param>
    /// <returns>Tuple of String, String (encrypted string, salt)</returns>
    public static Tuple<string, string> Encrypt(string plainTextString, string encryptionPassword)
    {
        byte[] Salt = new byte[16];
        var rnd = new Random();
        rnd.NextBytes(Salt);
        byte[] rawPlaintext = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainTextString);
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.KeySize = AesKeySizeInBits;
            int KeyStrengthInBytes = aes.KeySize / 8;
            var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionPassword, Salt, Rfc2898KeygenIterations);
            aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(KeyStrengthInBytes);
            aes.IV = rfc2898.GetBytes(KeyStrengthInBytes);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);
                }
                cipherText = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return new Tuple<string, string>(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(cipherText), Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Salt));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the decrypted string 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherTextString"></param>
    /// <param name="cipherSalt"></param>
    /// <param name="encryptionPassword"></param>
    /// <returns>String</returns>
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherTextString, string cipherSalt, string encryptionPassword)
    {
        byte[] Salt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cipherSalt);
        byte[] cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cipherTextString);
        byte[] plainText = null;
        using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.KeySize = AesKeySizeInBits;
            int KeyStrengthInBytes = aes.KeySize / 8;
            var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionPassword, Salt, Rfc2898KeygenIterations);
            aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(KeyStrengthInBytes);
            aes.IV = rfc2898.GetBytes(KeyStrengthInBytes);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                }
                plainText = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you can't use `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` to turn a bunch of random bytes into characters. Those random bytes are not guaranteed to form valid code points, and so `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` will not necessarily round-trip. Pass the salt as what it is, a `byte[]`. If you *must* store a string somewhere, use some other scheme (like `Convert.To/FromBase64String`), but I wouldn't put that in your inner methods.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Do you have some repro data?

Comment: Ya, It worked for me last night too

Comment: Nevermind, it repros sporatically, for the same input. Most likely due to what @JeroenMostert mentioned.

Comment: It is good practice to explicitly specify all parameters, in this case the mode: `CBC`.

Comment: Oh, and for "salt", of course the exact same applies to the "encrypted text". You are not getting back text, you're getting back a bunch of bytes. UTF-16 decoding/encoding does not roundtrip for arbitrary bytes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You were absolutely correct! Thank you. I actually ended up base 64 encoding it, so I didn't need to change any of the existing property and column types. If you post that as an official answer I will mark it as the accepted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` to turn random bytes into characters, because not all combinations are valid UTF-16 code point sequences. Upon encountering an illegal sequence, the decoder will fall back to giving you the `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, mangling your original bytes and making sure the decryption fails. Here's a simple piece of code to illustrate the problem:

```
byte[] b = new byte[4];
var r = new Random();
while (true) {
    r.NextBytes(b);
    var s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b);
    var expected = b;
    var actual = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
    if (!actual.SequenceEqual(expected)) {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Fail: expected {BitConverter.ToString(expected)}, " +
            $"got {BitConverter.ToString(actual)}"
        );
        break;
    }
}
```

This should fail very quickly with something along the lines of

> Fail: expected 3B-DC-5C-52, got FD-FF-5C-52

A simple fix is to use `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String` instead, as this does roundtrip.